# Visual studio 2012 wont install fully

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

Im trying to install visual studio 2012 to my 64bit windows 8 laptop but it just wont install fully, every time i run the application it keeps asking me to modify, repair or uninstall, I have done this many times and spent time trying to figure this out. I really need to install this soon. Is there something im doing wrong or is there something im missing. please help

Comment: What is the error which you are getting?

Comment: either it says to restart computer for it to run and when i do that it says that i need to repair components

Comment: Are you getting any error window? I am asking this as the solution may vary according to the message!

Answer (score 0):

could be your Windows installer corrupted. 
I would suggest you do a system restore to a working point, then be sure to run the setup in Administrator mode. What happens when you do this?

Comment: i downloaded it from dreamspark as im a student but i start it up no errors just says three things, modify, repair, uninstall.... nothing else

Comment: sure but that's not what im suggesting or saying.

Comment: Why don't you just empty your EventLog?

Comment: where do u go to find this event log, cant find it, I uninstalled it and reinstalled it and it worked but when i closed it down it then asks me to repair it

Comment: scratch that i fixed it